# Calculus 1 polynomials and derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, polynomials

Need your help with a Calculus 1 exercise.

Let $P,Q$ be polyomials with $deg(P)<deg(Q)$ and $Q(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots (x-a_n)$ where $a_i \neq a_j$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ and $i \neq j$. Show that if we write $$\frac{P}{Q}=\frac{A_1}{(x-a_1)}+\frac{A_2}{(x-a_2)}+ \cdots + \frac{A_n}{(x-a_n)}$$ then $A_j=P(a_j)/Q'(a_j)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

See that

$$P(x)= \frac{A_1Q(x)}{x-a_1}+h(x)$$

But

$$P(a_1)=A_1(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)...(a_1-a_n)+h(a_1)$$

But is easy to see that $h(a_1)=0$ and we also have $(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)...(a_1-a_n)=Q'(a_1)$.

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you sir, that was very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that $P,Q$ are polynomials with real coefficients and that $Q=(X-a_1)(X-a_2)\cdots(X-a_n)$ where the $a_i$ are pairwise distinct real numbers.

The theorem which gives the existence (and uniqueness) of partial fractions decomposition asserts that there exist real coefficients $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ such that :

$$\frac{P}{Q}=\frac{A_1}{X-a_1}+\cdots+\frac{A_n}{X-a_n}$$

Now, multiplying both sides by $Q$ and evaluating at $a_j$ for some $j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ leads to :

$$P(a_j)=A_j\prod_{i\neq j}(a_j-a_i)$$

But with know that :

$$Q'=\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{i\neq k}(X-a_i)$$  hence :

$$Q'(a_j)=\prod_{i\neq j}(a_j-a_i)$$

Finally :

$$\boxed{\frac{P}{Q}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\frac{P(a_i)}{Q'(a_i)}}{X-a_i}}$$